# where is weblogic.Server class?

Tags: java, jar, weblogic, classpath

i'm installed weblogic server from **wls1213_devzip_update1.zip** on **windows** and create instance in domain in my own directory and it work fine.

i'm try to install it on **linux mint 17.1 kde x64** and it work fine when i'm install instance in domain by default, but i got error when i'll try to install instance it in my own domain directory.

it can't find weblogic.Server class, although i acted on instruction in **README.txt**, i'll setup WLS environment in the current shell calles **$MW_HOME/wlserver/server/bin/setWLSEnv.sh**

i'll open **$MW_HOME/wlserver/server/lib/weblogic.jar** but found only **manifest.mf**

```
Main-Class: weblogic.Server
Class-Path: ...
```

I searched in classpaths, but not found it.

jdk1.8.0_40

Where weblogic.Server class is stored?

Thanks!

Comment: It is in the weblogic.jar file, if you can't find it in there your install is probably corrupt. Try `jar -tf <install_dir>/server/lib/weblogic.jar | grep Server.class` Sourcing `setWLSEnv.sh` will add that jar to your classpath.

Comment: @Display Name is missing - thanks, I tried, I even downloaded again wls1213_devzip_update1.zip,  but there really is no this file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the jar that you are looking for is in /Oracle_Home/wlserver/modules/features and is called weblogic.server.merged.jar.